# switch from current encoding to specified encoding is not supported

Tags: c#, sql, database, stored-procedures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khdmb.png)

import.sql((((
``

```
use `[D:\DBSD.CW2.14714.13786.12928\DBSD.CW2.14714.13786.12928\DBSD.CW2.14714.13786.12928\APPDATA\CAMBRIDGE.MDF]
--generating sample XML 
select top 2 EmployeeID "@id", FirstName "@fn", LastName "@ln", Position "@position",  HireDate "@hiredate", 1 as "@IsActive"
from Employee where Position is not null
for xml path('Employee'), root('Employees')

-------XML insert with id --------
declare @xml nvarchar(max) = '<Employees>
  <Employee id="400" fn="Margaret" ln="Park" position="Sales Support Agent" hiredate="2024-03-28" IsActive="1"/>
  <Employee id="500" fn="Steve" ln="Johnson" position="Sales Support Agent" hiredate="2024-03-28" IsActive="1"/>
</Employees>'

declare @xmlDocHandle int

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlDocHandle out--, @xml

set IDENTITY_INSERT employee on
insert into Employee(EmployeeID, FirstName, lastname, Position, IsActive, HireDate)
output inserted.*
select EmployeeID, FirstName, lastname, Position, IsActive, HireDate
from openxml(@xmlDocHandle, N'/Employees/Employee')
with(
  EmployeeID int '@id',
  FirstName nvarchar(200) '@fn',
  LastName nvarchar(200),
  Position nvarchar(100),
  IsActive bit '@IsActive',
  HireDate DATE '@hiredate'
)
set IDENTITY_INSERT employee off

------ XML insert with id generated by identity -----------
go
declare @xml nvarchar(max) = '<Employees>
  <Employee id="4" fn="Margaret" ln="Park" position="Sales Support Agent" hiredate="2024-03-28" IsActive="1"/>
  <Employee id="5" fn="Steve" ln="Johnson" position="Sales Support Agent" hiredate="2024-03-28" IsActive="1"/>
</Employees>'


go
create or alter procedure udpEmployeeImportFromXml(@xml nvarchar(2000))
as
begin
  declare @xmlDocHandle int
  exec sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlDocHandle out, @xml
  insert into Employee(firstname, lastname, Position, IsActive, HireDate)
  output inserted.*
  select firstname, ln, position, IsActive, HireDate
  from openxml(@xmlDocHandle, N'/Employees/Employee')
  with(
    EmployeeID int '@id',
    FirstName nvarchar(200) '@fn',
    ln nvarchar(200),
    position nvarchar(100),
    IsActive BIT '@IsActive',
      HireDate DATE '@hiredate'
  )
end
---
go
exec udpEmployeeImportFromXml '<Employees>
  <Employee id="4" fn="Margaret" ln="Park" position="Agent" hiredate="2024-03-28" IsActive="1"/>
  <Employee id="5" fn="Steve" ln="Johnson" position="Agent" hiredate="2024-03-28" IsActive="1"/>
</Employees>'

select * from employee

-------------- JSON import ----------------------
--generating sample JSON 
select top 2 EmployeeID "id", FirstName "fn", LastName "ln", Position "position", HireDate "@hiredate", 1 as "@IsActive"
from Employee where position is not null
for json path
go
---- json without root wrapper
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '[
  {
    "id": 9356,
    "fn": "Margaret",
    "ln": "Park",
    "position": "Sales Support Agent",
  "hiredate": "2023-01-15",
    "IsActive": true 
  },
  {
    "id": 6985,
    "fn": "Steve",
    "ln": "Johnson",
    "position": "Sales Support Agent"
  "hiredate": "2023-04-15",
    "IsActive": true 
  }
]';


--Test again 
select *
from openjson(@json)
with(
   id int,
   fn nvarchar(200),
   ln nvarchar(200),
   position nvarchar(100),
   hiredate DATE '$.hiredate',
   IsActive BIT '$.IsActive'
);


------------- Json with root wrapper ----
select top 2 EmployeeID "id", FirstName "fn", LastName "ln", Position "position", HireDate "@hiredate", 1 A S "@IsActive"
from Employee where position is not null
for json path
go
---- json without root wrapper
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
  "Employee":[
    {
      "id": 4,
      "fn": "Margaret",
      "ln": "Park",
      "position": "Sales Support Agent",
      "hiredate": "2023-01-15",
      "IsActive": true
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "fn": "Steve",
      "ln": "Johnson",
      "position": "Sales Support Agent",
      "hiredate": "2023-01-15",
      "IsActive": true
    }
  ]
}'
go
create or alter procedure udpEmployeeImportFromJson(@json nvarchar(max))
as
begin
    insert into Employee(firstname, lastname, Position, HireDate, IsActive)
    output inserted.*
    select fn, ln, position, HireDate, IsActive
    from openjson(@json, '$.Employee')
    with(
     id int '$.id',
     fn nvarchar(200),
     ln nvarchar(200),
     position nvarchar(100),
     IsActive BIT '@IsActive',
     HireDate DATE '@hiredate'
  )
end
--- test

---test again
go
EXEC udpEmployeeImportFromJson '{"Employee":[{"id":4,"fn":"Margaret","ln":"Park","position":"Sales Support Agent","IsActive":true,"hiredate": "2023-01-15"},{"id":5,"fn":"Steve","ln":"Johnson","position":"Sales Support Agent","IsActive":true,"hiredate": "2023-01-15"}]}'

`
```

`
))))

Good Day. I am trying to import json and xml file to my database. so I can insert data from there but once I have choosen the nexessary file it is showing me the error that i showed above as screenshot. I dont know if it is in the import.sql or repository itself. thank you all for your reponse beforehand